# API call in Chrome Extension requires two button presses

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome extension that injects an HTML form on a page through inject.js and when a query is entered and the button is pressed an API call is made through background.js. The contents are then brought back to the inject.js script and processed.

When I first try to make a call through inject.js I get the following error:

```
    Error in event handler for 'undefined': fetchResult is not defined ReferenceError: searchResult is not defined
```

Oddly enough when I wait a little and press again the query is fetched.

I'm suspecting fetchresult is undefined the first time because it takes a couple of moments to fetch the query but I don't know how to fix this.

inject.js:

```
    function fetch() {

    var fetchResult;

    var fetchquery = document.getElementById('field').value;

    chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting: fetchquery}, function(response) {
             fetchResults = response.farewell
            constructHTML(fetchResultsResults)      

        });
    };
```

background.js:

```
    function loadXMLDoc(query)
    {

   if (query){
    // new cross origin XML request

   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         fetchResult = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
         }
     }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&q="+query, true);
   xmlhttp.send();

   return fetchResult;

   } else {

       return "noquery";
    }
    };

    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
       if (loadXMLDoc(request.greeting) != "noquery"){
            sendResponse({farewell: loadXMLDoc(request.greeting)})
            }
    });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest is *asynchronous*, so instead of `return fetchResult`, you should invoke a callback to pass the result. Here's an example:

```
   function loadXMLDoc(query, callback)
   {

   if (query){
    // new cross origin XML request

   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
      {
         if(xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
           fetchResult = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
           callback(fetchResult);
         } else {
           callback("noquery");
         }
      }
     }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&q="+query, true);
   xmlhttp.send();

   } else {

       callback("noquery");
    }
    };

    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            loadXMLDoc(request.greeting, function(fetchResult) {
              if (fetchResult != "noquery")
                sendResponse({farewell: fetchResult})
              else
                sendResponse({});
            });
            return true; // See the description of https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#property-onMessage-sendResponse.
    });
```